# Are the first 4 bytes of a Ed25519 public key random?

Tags: public-key, entropy, ed25519

We are using the Ed25519 signature scheme (which uses Curve25519). A key pair is generated by generating the secret key from random data and then computing the 32-byte (256-bit) public key from said secret key.

The question is about the entropy (randomness) of the public key. We currently use the first 4 bytes of the public key as a "reasonably unique" ID of the public key. We have very limited space and cannot afford more than 4 bytes. Would we improve the uniqueness of the ID if we generate it differently? For example, the ID could be generated by XOR between Bytes 0-3 and Bytes 4-7 of the public key? Or using the first 4 bytes of sha-512 of the public key. Or what?

Comment: If you have 10k public keys, then with probability circa 1% two will share the first 4 bytes; with the probability growing sharply as you add more keys.  No, there's no other way of generating 4 byte IDs that improve on this...

Comment: @poncho Using the first 4 bytes of a hash over the public key cannot be worse right, or are the most significant bits perfectly distributed? Still, yeah, 4 bytes is not enough for a large number of public keys. A simple counter would be an option? > 4 billion keys...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: actually, Curve25519 is traditionally encoded in  little-endian order, and so the first 4 bytes are the lower 32 bits, and so we'd expect them to look random.

Comment: Ah yeah, with little endian it makes more sense :)

Comment: @poncho can you be bothered to pack your first comment into an answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 32-bit ids are assigned *independently*, the best you can hope for with a uniform random assignment of ids is a collision probability no more than about $n^2/2^{32}$ where $n$ is the number of ids you have, if $n$ is small; once $n$ grows past $2^{16}$ the probability of a collision rapidly approaches 1.  This is the [standard birthday paradox](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68203).

Using a nonuniform distribution on ids is even worse.  The distribution of bits in the encoding of uniform random *curve points* is detectably nonuniform—enough that it was one of the [first problems reported in Dual_EC_DRBG](https://web.archive.org/web/20110525081912/http://www.math.ntnu.no/~kristiag/drafts/dual-ec-drbg-comments.pdf) before everyone realized there was a back door.  The low-order 32 bits are *probably* close enough to uniform in this case that it won't affect the collision probabilities; to alleviate that concern you could pass the encoded curve point through a hash like SHAKE128-32 first.

But you should be more concerned with what you hope to achieve using 32-bit ids in the first place!  This has been a consistent source of trouble in OpenPGP, for example—fraudulent keys have been forged and uploaded to the key servers for *every* 32-bit key id possible.  To avoid this trouble, you fundamentally need to:

1. make the id assignments *non-independent*, *e.g.* use a secret permutation of 32-bit strings so that you can have up to four billion ids
2. use a much larger id space, *e.g.* 256 bits
3. accept that collisions will happen and find a way to deal with them gracefully, even under adversarial inputs that are *all* collisions